# Value of request params is empty if i use = symbol with request value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am working on node.js project which uses express framework . 
My application will process bunch of POST requests . One of my post request is follows

**URL**

```
POST /processit
```

**request params**

```
info={"one":"a=5"}
```

**node.js code**

```
     var express = require('express');
       var app = express();
       app.use(express.bodyParser());
       app.post('/processit', function(req, res) {
         console.log(req.body);
         res.type('text/plain');
         res.send('Testing !');
      });

   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

In node.js log i am getting respone

```
{}
```

But if i change request params from `info={"one":"a=5"}` to `info={"one":"ab5"}` i am getting

```
info={"one":"ab5"}
```

in node.js log .

I don't know whether i did anything wrong here

ScreenShot :
[image]

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What format is that body supposed to be? How is `bodyParser` supposed to handle it?

Comment: As of now i am using plain text .

Comment: @Nagarajan I also couldn't reproduce it. They both work fine without any header information. When I changed the header to `application/json` (i had to cut down `info=`), it still worked fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye I have attached my screenshot . i don't know what i am doing wrong here ! .

When i used info={"one":"ab5"} i am getting first response {} . Later when i use info={"one":"ab5"} i am getting response what i expect !

Comment: Can you show us (screenshot/post code) how the request looks like for `info={"one":"a=5"}`? I had expected you were sending this as the `body`, not as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is with how your Eclipse test tool is encoding things.

Try doing your POST with curl from the command line, or this Chrome plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en